# Shift all Items in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array like this:

```
$arr[0][0] = array('key' => 'value', 'key1' => 'value1', ...);
$arr[0][1] = array(...);
$arr[1][0] = array(...);
```

Now I would like to shift all items in $arr[0] to result in something like this:

```
$arr[0][0] = undefined;
$arr[0][1] = array('key' => 'value', 'key1' => 'value1', ...);
$arr[0][2] = array(...);
$arr[1][0] = array(...);
```

I tried this with `for()`-loops, and `while()`-loops, but both methods did not work for me, they are doing a mess with the result.

Comment: did you actually even try [googling this](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+array+shift)? Or reading the php manual?

Comment: Yes, of course. I just didn't know whats the right search term for this problem. Hint: "Shift entire array PHP" is not correct.

Comment: if you googled it, you should have found the `array_shift()` and `array_unshift()` functions. If you found them, did you try them? (I get it that your example isn't a simple flat array, but with a bit of work you should have got somewhere with them. If you didn't try them, you should do so. And if you *did* try them and they didn't work for you, you should probably have said so in the question. Maybe show some of the code you've tried, so we know how close you are to a solution.

Comment: `for($m = 0; $m < count($arr[0]); $m++) { $temp = &$arr[0][($m+1)]; $arr[0][($m+1)] = &$arr[0][$m]; }`

Comment: @MartinWeise FYI, that method fails because when you move the 1st element to the 2nd, the 2nd is overridden - it would have worked had you worked from `count` backwards to 0 (if that makes sense). Though my answer is much easier, so forget that method for now lol!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
array_unshift($arr[0],'first elem');
```

[PHP Doc - unshift()](https://www.php.net/array_unshift)

> array_unshift — Prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an array